# Unsure how to make plt.hist2d actually return variables

Tags: python, matplotlib, 2d, histogram

According to the documentation for the `plt.hist2d` function, it should both plot a density distribution and return three variables: `xedges`, `yedges`, and `h`. `h` should be the bi-dimensional histogram of the samples, e.g. the two-dimensional array plotted. However, when I use this function it appears to think I am asking it to return more than three variables. I am running:

```
myHist, xedges, yedges = plt.hist2d(X, Y, bins=(np.linspace(-0.5,2,50),np.linspace(0,2.5,50)), cmap=plt.cm.Reds, cmin=1)
```

and getting the error:
`ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)`

Any advice? I am using python3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d.html) for hist2d method, it returns four variables: `h`, `xedges`, `yedges`, and `image`.

> Returns:
>
> h : 2D array The bi-dimensional histogram of samples x and
> y. Values in x are histogrammed along the first dimension and values
> in y are histogrammed along the second dimension.
>
> xedges : 1D array The bin edges along the x axis.
>
> yedges : 1D array The bin edges along the y axis.
>
> image : QuadMesh

Comment: Thank you @Harben. So then I should really be using ```myHist, xedges, yedges, image = plt.hist2d(X, Y, bins=(np.linspace(-0.5,2,50),np.linspace(0,2.5,50)), cmap=plt.cm.Reds, cmin=1)``` ? Then do I need to plot the image (in which case, would ```plt.plot(image)``` work?), or should it just still create a plot without needing to plot ```image```? Functionally, what is the difference between ```image``` and ```h```?

Comment: @user1093541 yes, you need that fourth variable in order for the unpacking to succeed. `plt.show()` will suffice in this instance.